# Problem with checkboxes in eclipse with dark theme (white on white)

Tags: eclipse, checkbox, themes

I use eclipse with devstyle plugin and set the theme to Dark Grey (Darkest Dark)
The problem is that check boxes are white and check marks in them are also white.
See in this image where i have my arrow there is a very light check mark in a white checkbox.

[image]

Can this be fixed ?

Comment: Hello! Can you give me more information about your particular install (OS, Arch, Eclipse version, OS Level Theme)? If on Linux you should make sure your OS level theme is Dark friendly as most widgets are rendered by the OS and they can conflict with the styling bits that come from the DevStyle theme.

Comment: @AaronIsaacLaraOtero Isaac Lara Otero Oracle Linux Server release 6.6, kernel 3.8.13, Eclipse is Neon, i running remote X content from that machine to my windows machine using SGD (secure global desktop - ex-Tarantella ). I am not sure how using SGD affects the window manager that is used or how it relates to the theme - do you have any link i can learn about it ?

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm not faimiliar with Oracle Linux server, but you should be able to change the OS theme it runs with to something dark friendly. Maybe this link helps in your case https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-7282/themes-0/index.html (see Using Themes to Customize the Desktop) ...